# AWS Glue Crawler - Crawl new folders only - Internal Service Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have created a glue crawler to run every 6 hours , I am using "Crawl new folders only" option. Every time crawler runs it fails with "Internal Service Exception" error.

What I tried so far ?

1. Created another crawler with option "Crawl all the folders" set to run every 6 hours. It works perfectly without any issue.
2. Created another crawler with option "Crawl new folders only" but with "Run on demand" option. It works perfectly without any issue.

All above 3 scenarios point to same S3 bucket with same IAM policy rule. I also tried reducing 6 hours run time to 15 mins / 1 hour but no luck.

What I am missing ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might consider raising a support ticket with AWS and provide enough info for them to pull logs.

Comment: Any body else faced similar issue ?

Comment: Yes. I am facing the same issue. Changed the recrawl policy to new folders only and it has been failing with Internal Exception but works fine when the recrawl policy is set to all folders. The cloudwatch logs isn’t giving much information. Pretty strange!

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting `RecrawlPolicy` as `CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY` then please make sure that the `UpdateBehavior` is `LOG` only otherwise you will get the error like `The SchemaChangePolicy for "Crawl new folders only" Amazon S3 target can have only LOG DeleteBehavior value and LOG UpdateBehavior value.`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the Glue console.

After changing the parameter to `Recrawl new only` in step 2. I made sure to select the following options in **Step 4 > Set output and scheduling > Output configuration > Advanced options**

When the crawler detects schema changes in the data store, how should AWS Glue handle table updates in the data catalog?:

- Ignore the change and don't update the table in the data catalog

How should AWS Glue handle deleted objects in the data store?:

- Ignore the change and don't update the table in the data catalog